# Embedding a Ruby interpreter in C, SIGSEGV

Tags: c, ruby

Im trying example of how to embedding ruby interpreter from Programming Ruby book. But its still not working. I have Ruby installed with RVM.

My source files: https://gist.github.com/1635374

Ruby version:

```
    $ ruby -v
    ruby 1.9.2p290 (2011-07-09 revision 32553) [i686-linux]
```

Location of Ruby header file:

```
    $ locate ruby.h
    ...
    /home/matej/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby.h
    /home/matej/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/ruby.h
    ...
```

Location of Ruby libraries:

```
    $ locate libruby.so.1
    /home/matej/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/libruby.so.1.9
    /home/matej/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/libruby.so.1.9.1
```

Make:

```
    $ make
    cc -I/home/matej/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/include/ruby-1.9.1/ -I/home/matej/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/include/ruby-1.9.1/i686-linux/ -g   -c -o embed2.o embed2.c
    cc -o embed2 embed2.o -shared  -L/home/matej/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib -ldl -lruby1.9
```

Run program:

```
    $./embed2
```

Causes SIGSEGV.

Can you help me please to find, where is the problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried gdb to find out where it actually crashes?

Answer (score 3):

Try compiling with additional debugging symbols (e.g. `-ggdb` if using GCC/GDB) and running your program in a debugger to see what causes the segmentation fault.

Comment: Thats good idea. `(gdb) file embed2
Reading symbols from /home/matej/Programming/Ruby/ruby_ext_example/embed2...done.
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/matej/Programming/Ruby/ruby_ext_example/embed2 

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00000001 in ?? ()
` Well but Im not much more clever from this...

Comment: @matejuh: where did you set a breakpoint?  The tool isn't going to automatically solve your problem, you need to think about it and how to use it effectively.

Comment: I know, Im sorry for that. I have never used gdb before... In my previous projects I used Valgrind...

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out the problem after 2 hour spend on it. `-shared` parameter caused it from some reason. In book example there isnt this parametr and I added it because of my previous problems with libruby loading. It can be find in makefile made by `extconf`.